# KSCrash simple callback function?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using KSCrash to crash detect.
when crash detected i want to call my function and send to it the crash log ,
In my function I send the crash log to my server side through my API

I don't need all of that

```
 KSCrashInstallation* installation = [self makeEmailInstallation]; 
KSCrashInstallation* installation = [self makeHockeyInstallation];
 KSCrashInstallation* installation = [self makeQuincyInstallation];
KSCrashInstallation *installation = [self makeVictoryInstallation];
```

the question is can i do that just call back function when detect crash and to be static like "on crash" ?